# Count "greater" occurrences without loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, broadcasting

Let's assume that we have an array `A` if shape `(100,)` and `B` of shape `(10,)`. Both contain values in [0,1].

How do we get the count of elements in `A` greater than each value in `B`? I expect an of shape `(10,)`, where the first element is "how many in `A` are greater than `B[0]`", the second is "how many in `A` are greater than `B[1]`", etc ...

Without using loops.

I tried the following, but it didn't work :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rdm

A = rdm.rand(100)
B = np.linspace(0,1,10)
def occ(z: float) ->float:
     return np.count_nonzero(A > z)
occ(B)
```

Python won't use my function as a scalar function on `B`, that's why I get:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (100,)
```

I've also tried with `np.greater` but I've got the same issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Slow But Simple**

The error message is cryptic if you don't understand it, but it's telling you what to do. Array dimensions are [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) together by lining them up starting with the right edge. This is especially helpful if you split your operation into two parts:

1. Create a `(100, 10)` mask showing which elements of `A` are greater than which elements of `B`:

   ```
    mask = A[:, None] > B
   ```
2. Sum the result of the previous operation along the axis corresponding to `A`:

   ```
    result = np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0)
   ```

   OR

   ```
    result = np.sum(mask, axis=0)
   ```

This can be written as a one-liner:

```
(A[:, None] > B).sum(0)
```

OR

```
np.count_nonzero(A[:, None] > B, axis=0)
```

You can switch the dimensions and place `B` in the first axis to get the same result:

```
(A > B[:, None]).sum(1)
```

**Fast and Elegant**

Taking a totally different (but likely much more efficient) approach, you can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
A.sort()
result = A.size - np.searchsorted(A, B)
```

By default, `searchsorted` returns the left-index that each element of `B` would be inserted into `A` at. That pretty much immediately tells you how many elements of `A` are greater than that.

**Benchmarks**

Here, the algos are labeled as follows:

- `B0`: `(A[:, None] > B).sum(0)`
- `B1`: `(A > B[:, None]).sum(1)`
- `HH`: `np.cumsum(np.histogram(A, bins=B)[0][::-1])[::-1]`
- `SS`: `A.sort();  A.size - np.searchsorted(A, B)`

```
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| A.size | B.size |        Time (B0 / B1 / HH / SS)        |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|    100 |     10 |  20.9 µs / 15.7 µs / 68.3 µs / 8.87 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|   1000 |     10 |   118 µs / 57.2 µs /  139 µs / 17.8 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|  10000 |     10 |   987 µs /  288 µs / 1.23 ms /  131 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 100000 |     10 |  9.48 ms / 2.77 ms / 13.4 ms / 1.42 ms |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|    100 |    100 |  70.7 µs / 63.8 µs /   71 µs / 11.4 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|   1000 |    100 |   518 µs /  388 µs /  148 µs / 21.6 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|  10000 |    100 |  4.91 ms / 2.67 ms / 1.22 ms /  137 µs |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 100000 |    100 |  57.4 ms / 35.6 ms / 13.5 ms / 1.42 ms |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

Memory layout matters. `B1` is always faster than `B0`. This happens because summing contiguous (cached) elements (along the last axis in C-order) is always faster than having to skip across rows to get the next element. Broadcasting performs well for small values of `B`. Keep in mind that both the time and space complexity for `B0` and `B1` is `O(A.size * B.size)`. The complexity of the two histogramming solutions should be about `O(A.size * log(A.size))`, but `SS` is implemented much more efficiently than `HH` because it can assume more things about the data.

Comment: Works perfect now. Is there a gain in performance using this instead of loop ? Would you use this solution or another ?

Comment: @SleepWaterTea. I would use the `searchsorted` solution

Comment: Ha, I had not noticed who wrote this answer :-)

The fast approach is probably the best answer for this particular question. However, it is important to understand broadcasting in general, as it applies to many other cases. Except that sort operations can be VERY slow if the arrays are large.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez. That's exactly why I started with a preamble about the simple approach :)

Comment: Right. I was just pointing it out. One thing: the first approach is faster in my machine if the length of A is larger than about 1000. As size increases it scales better.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez. I dunno. `searchsorted` is always faster on my machine, by a lot. I posted some benchmarks.

Comment: @SleepWaterTea. I added some benchmarks to show why I would always use the `searchsorted` approach

Comment: Nice benchmark table. To add to your estimates of complexity: The complexity of `HH` partly comes from the sorting, which you can realistically expect it to be `O(A.size * log(A.size))`, so it would be  `O(A.size * log(A.size) * B.size)`

Comment: @Javier. The elements of B must already be sorted, so it's more like `O(A.size * log(B.size))`: each element of A gets a binary search into B. Searchsorted is faster because it does the opposite: placing each element of B into A is `O(B.size * log(A.size))` sorting A is `O(A.size * log(A.size))`. The two are comparable, but sort and searchsorted just have much less overhead than making a histogram

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment I meant `SS` (which you did not explicitly add in your answer). The complexity of `SS` is `O((A.size + B.size) * log(A.size) )`. It follows exactly from your last comment. Corrected it.

Comment: @Javier. Agreed. I didn't list it explicitly since if `A.size > B.size`, `O(A.size + B.size) = O(2 * A.size) = O(A.size)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [np.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for this job

```
A = rdm.rand(100)
B = np.linspace(0,1,10)
np.histogram(A, bins=B)[0]
```

Gives the output

```
array([10,  9,  8, 11,  9, 14, 10, 12, 17])
```

`B[9]` will always be empty because there are no values > 1.

And compute the cumsum backwards

```
np.cumsum(np.histogram(A, bins=B)[0][::-1])[::-1]
```

Output

```
array([100,  90,  81,  73,  62,  53,  39,  29,  17])
```

Comment: You have to be careful here, because `B` is interpreted as bin edges. Make sure you append `A.max() + 1` or similar to `B`, and don't forget to take the cumulative sum at the end. Aside from that, this is a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.sum(A>B.reshape((-1,1)), axis=1)
```

**Explanation**

Need to understand [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and reshaping for this. By reshaping B to shape (len(B), 1), it can be broadcasted with A to produce an array with shape (len(B), len(A)) containing all comparisons. Then you sum over axis 1 (along A).

In other words, `A < B` does not work because `A` has 100 entries, and B has 10. If you read the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules), you will see that numpy will start with the last dimension, and if they are the same size, then it can compare one-to-one. If one of the two is `1`, then this dimension is *stretched or “copied” to match the other*. If they are not equal and none of them is equal to `1`, it fails.

With a shorter example:

```
A = np.array([0.5112744 , 0.21696187, 0.14710105, 0.98581087, 0.50053359,
              0.54954654, 0.81217522, 0.50009166, 0.42990167, 0.56078499])
B = array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75])
```

the transpose of `(A>B.reshape((-1,1)))` (for readability)

```
np.array([[ True,  True, False],
          [False, False, False],
          [False, False, False],
          [ True,  True,  True],
          [ True,  True, False],
          [ True,  True, False],
          [ True,  True,  True],
          [ True,  True, False],
          [ True, False, False],
          [ True,  True, False]])
```

and `np.sum(A>B.reshape((-1,1)), axis=1)` is

```
array([8, 7, 2])
```

Comment: There's a typo in your prose. -1 -> 1